# deny parallel ssh connection to server for specific host / IP

Tags: bash, session, unix, ssh, parallel-processing

> 1. I have a bot machine (controlled via mobile device) which
>      connects to the Server and fetch information from it by method os
>      "ssh, shell script, os commands,sql queries etc" than it feed that
>      information over the internet (private)
> 2. I want to disallow this multiple connection to the server via the
>      bot machine ONLY.. there are other machine which connects to the server which must not be affected

**Suppose**

> Client A from his mobile acess bot machine (via webpage) than the bot
>   machine connect to server (1st session) now if the process of this
>   connection is 5 minute during this period the bot machine will be
>   creating, quering, deleting, appending, updating etc
>
> in the very mean time of that 5 minute duration (suppose 2min after
>   the 1st session started) Client B from his mobile access bot machine
>   (via webpage) than the bot machine connect to server (2nd session) now
>   it will conflict with the 1st session and create Havoc...

**Limitation**

> 1. Now first of all i do not want to editing any setting on the SERVER
>      ANY WHAT SO EVER
> 2. I do not want to edit the webpage/mobile etc
> 3. I already know abt the lock file method of parallel shell script and
>      it is implemented at script  level but what abt the OS commands and
>      stuff like that which are not in bash script

**My Thougth**

> What i thougt was whenever we create a connection with server it
>   create a process named what ever (*SSH*) which is viewable in ps -fu
>   OSUSER so by applying a unique id/tag/name to our connection we can
>   identify if one session is active or not. This will be check as soon
>   as the bot connects to the server. But i do not know how to do
>   that.... Please also suggest any more information over it.
>   Also is there is way to identify if the existing process is hanged or
>   the time of the process started or elapsed?

Comment: there are no magic "OS commands and stuff like that" that can achieve what you seem to want to do.  A lockfile seems to be the most obvious and simple thing to do

Comment: So in short do you mean to say that after SSH session connection is made check for lock file ? as it is directed for avoiding parallel running same shell Shell scripts ? Even if so my next question will be how to idetify if the previous session is hanged or taking to long etc.. without knowing that the next connection (after a hanged session) will see the lock file and will not be able to connect atall ... how to deal with that problem ?

Comment: Also you got me wrong in there on limitation point three i mentioned that i know abt lock method and explained it.. But i do not want to use lock method here like they do in shell script.. so i wanted to know alternative method.. why -1 point when it is a geniune question ? also do check my previous comment for next question over it.

Comment: -1 because the question is difficult to read and is arguably about server configuration and not programming

Comment: atleast provide answer to my other question over the subject.. Also please suggest which lock method will be good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try using limits.conf to enforce a hard limit of 1 login for the user/group.

You might need a periodic cron job to check for and remove any stale logins.

Locks/mutexes are hard to get right and add complexity. Limits.conf is a standard feature of most unix/linux systems and should be more reliable, emphasis on should...

A similar question was raised here:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/127077/number-of-ssh-connections-on-a-single-linux-machine

Details here:
http://linux.die.net/man/5/limits.conf

Comment: i want to ask the limis.conf solution is for bot or for the server ? where should we implement it ? If server than it is not possible. If bot than it is possible but just that it is not proper solution. But it is good solution just in not my case

Comment: It's a setting on the server. I interpreted your 'Limitation #1' as something not to do every login, as opposed to something done only once on the server. The lockfile solution is also a change to the login script on the server, so it is a server side solution too...

Comment: i cannot do the limits.conf because at the same time many other ips are logged in. I mean bot will have logged in 24/7 but many other pcs will also loging so "i think" that limits.conf will disable all logins. Also want to say to you that the user/group are used are common and same by all the user loging in remotely. There is no seprate user/grp.

Comment: If all users are sharing the same id and group, and thus there is no differentiation on the server side between users, and you cannot make any change to the server, then you have very few options left. The only possibility I see is to run your own lockfile creation and checking commands manually on every login.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have a single login for the ssh account and that this runs a script on login

Add something like this to the script at login

```
#!/bin/bash
LOCK_FILE="/tmp/sshlock"
trap "rm $LOCK_FILE; exit" SIGHUP SIGINT SIGTERM

if [ $(( (`date +%s` - `stat -L --format %Y $LOCK_FILE`) < (30*60) )) ]; then
   exit 0
fi
touch $LOCK_FILE
```

When the processes that the ssh login calls end, delete the $LOCK_FILE

The `trap` statement is an important part of this way of locking, please do use it

The "30*60" is a 30 minute timeout, thanks to the answer on this question [How can I tell if a file is older than 30 minutes from /bin/sh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005021/how-can-i-tell-if-a-file-is-older-than-30-minutes-from-bin-sh)

Comment: It is very good solution but i need a little explanation on this... Please sir explain on how it will work (i am seeing the trap command very very first time)...Also please explain if a problem occurs like my 1st ssh session gets hang/taking too much time than in that situation how this will function. Also can i kill that hanged session with the new session ? if yes than how (please add code)?  please don't mind i am just trying to enhance it and i am very new to this.

Comment: Also It is very good solution and i am thinking of making two part of the script Part A and Part B when we start the session the Part A will run when we are done with all activity part B will run in the End is it okay or is thre any flaw in this ?

Comment: I also would like to update that above code gives problem likestat: cannot stat `/disk1/checkbot/sshlock': No such file or directory
script1.sh: line 5: (1412532532 - ) < (30*60) : syntax error: operand expected (error token is ") < (30*60) ")
sleep: invalid time interval